# Erro: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php, mysqli

No meu projeto coloquei uma barra de pesquisa, na qual o usuário informa um valor a ser pesquisado e seleciona a coluna na qual ele quer pesquisar. 
O que vai ser pesquisado vem de um campo input type="text" e a coluna de um input type="radio", ambos no mesmo formulário.
 O problema é que, quando insiro as variáveis com os valores trazidos do formulário, o php me retorna um erro:

> mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\php\listar_cliente.php on line 178

```
  <?php
  //Início da listagem

  $coluna = $_POST['coluna'];
  $pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa'];

  $servidor = 'localhost';
  $usuario = 'root';
  $senha = '';
  $banco = 'portfolio';

if( $pesquisa == "")
{   
    if( ($coluna == "") or ($coluna == "tudo"))
    {
        $COMANDO_SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente ";        
    }
}
else
{
    $COMANDO_SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE '".$coluna."' LIKE '%'".$pesquisa."'%' ";   
}

$link = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);
$resultado_listagem = mysqli_query($link,$COMANDO_SQL);  
?>
```

Php para a listagem:

```
<?php
        while( $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_listagem) )
        {   
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="CPF/CNPJ"><?php echo $linha['CPF_CNPJ']; ?></td>
                <td data-title="Nome/Razão Social"><?php echo $linha['NOME_COMPLETO_RAZAO_SOCIAL']; ?></td>
                <td data-title="Nome Fantasia"><?php echo $linha['NOME_FANTASIA']; ?></td>
                <td data-title="Telefone"><?php echo $linha['TELEFONE'];     ?></td>
                <td data-title="Rua"><?php echo $linha['RUA']; ?></td>
                <td data-title="Bairro"><?php echo $linha['BAIRRO']; ?></td>
                <td data-title="Cidade"><?php echo $linha['CIDADE'];; ?></td>
                <td data-title="Estado"><?php echo $linha['ESTADO']; ?></td>
                <td data-title="Ações">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
                        data-cpf="<?php echo $linha['CPF_CNPJ']; ?>"
                        data-nome="<?php echo $linha['NOME_COMPLETO_RAZAO_SOCIAL']; ?>"
                        data-nomefantasia="<?php echo $linha['NOME_FANTASIA']; ?>"
                        data-telefone="<?php echo $linha['TELEFONE']; ?>" 
                        data-rua="<?php echo $linha['RUA']; ?>" 
                        data-bairro="<?php echo $linha['BAIRRO']; ?>"
                        data-cidade="<?php echo $linha['CIDADE']; ?>"
                        data-estado="<?php echo $linha['ESTADO']; ?>" >
                        Editar
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td data-title=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Código do formulário HTML:

```
<!-- BARRA DE PESQUISA -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="listar_cliente.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar por..." >
                    <button class="btn " type="submit">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>  
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="tudo" > Todos os dados 
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="CPF_CNPJ" > CPF/CNPJ   
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="NOME_COMPLETO_RAZAO_SOCIAL"> Nome
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="NOME_FANTASIA"> Nome Fantasia
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="TELEFONE"> Telefone
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="RUA"> Rua
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="BAIRRO"> Bairro
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="CIDADE"> Cidade
                <input type="radio" name="coluna" id="coluna" value="ESTADO"> Estado
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual erro ele te retorna? Cola a mensagem inteira.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\php\listar_cliente.php on line 178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, as colunas não podem ficar entre aspas simples:

```
... WHERE '".$coluna."'
```

Segundo ao fazer isto:

```
LIKE '%'".$pesquisa."'%'
```

É provavel que esteja gerando algo como:

```
LIKE '%'exemplo'%'
```

Ou seja a pesquisa não esta dentro do LIKE, tem aspas a mais.

O correto provavelmente seria algo como:

```
"SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE ".$coluna." LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%'"
```

Agora o mais importante, faça sempre a checagem do mysqli_query, pode usar `die`, por exemplo:

```
else
{
    $COMANDO_SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE ".$coluna." LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%'";   
}

$link = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);
$resultado_listagem = mysqli_query($link, $COMANDO_SQL) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Assim evita de entrar no while acaso ocorra alguma falha.

Comment: Os problema estava nas apas mesmo. Achei que a sintaxe estivesse correta, pois sempre usei essa forma ' ".$variavel." ' para concatenar variáveis em comando sql.

Comment: Tanto é que na função que uso para salvar os dados, o comando sql apresenta aspas simples na coluna

$COMANDO_SQL_CLIENTE = "INSERT INTO cliente (
        CPF_CNPJ,
        TELEFONE,
        NOME_COMPLETO_RAZAO_SOCIAL,
        NOME_FANTASIA,
        CIDADE,
        RUA,
        ESTADO,
        BAIRRO)
         values(
         '".$CPF_CNPJ."',
         '".$TELEFONE."',
         '".$NOME_COMPLETO_RAZAO_SOCIAL."',
         '".$NOME_FANTASIA."',
         '".$CIDADE."',
         '".$RUA."',
         '".$ESTADO."',
         '".$BAIRRO."')";

Comment: @Igor não, isso não são as colunas, são os "valores" das colunas, as colunas são a parte que esta sem aspas: `CPF_CNPJ, TELEFONE, NOME_COMPLETO_RAZAO_SOCIAL, NOME_FANTASIA, CIDADE, RUA, ESTADO, BAIRRO`. Resumindo: Valores usam aspas, colunas não usam ;)

Comment: De fato, cometi um baita engano. Grato por tudo cara<Joinha aqui>.

Answer (score 1):

Então pelo o que eu pude perceber você está fazendo de forma errada 
tenta isso aqui. utilizo praticamente a mesma coisa em uma das minhas aplicações,
como o `comando` que você está passando para o banco já esta dentro do `php` não tem o porque concatenar basta você chamar a variável normalmente.
Utilize o seguinte comando 'sql':

$COMANDO_SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE '$coluna' LIKE '%$pesquisa%' ";

Comment: Continua nem retornando o mesmo erro
" mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\php\listar_cliente.php on line 178"